# What is the relationship between Martian Manhunter and Wonder Woman in Justice League Unlimited series?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, justice-league-unlimited

In Justice League Unlimited animated series wonder woman seems to be very caring and understanding for Martian Manhunter. She even hugs him 2 times in series, she appears to be the member who is most close to mm in justice league. She appears to love him as a good friend or brother but what exactly is the relationship between them what it is like please support your answer with reasons and evidences from Justice League Unlimited series.

Comment: I can't see anything special among them MM had better bonding with superman.

Comment: We never really saw much outside of her being his friend and the exchange where she worked to convince him to try to spend more time around humanity.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question right there?